# How to provide linker options when linking a static library with qmake?

Tags: qt, qmake

I want to provide options to the linker when building a **static library** using qmake. Say I'd want to get verbose linker output when building with MSVC. The project file looks as follows:

```
# mylib.pro
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = mylib
CONFIG += staticlib
QT += core
win32-msvc*: QMAKE_LFLAGS += /VERBOSE
unix: QMAKE_LFLAGS += -v
```

That's the entire project file. It should result in an empty static library with no objects in it.

Setting neither `QMAKE_LFLAGS` nor `QMAKE_LFLAGS_STATIC_LIB` nor `LIBS` has any effect on the linker. Nothing set in those variables even makes it to the Makefile. If `QMAKE_LFLAGS` worked, I'd expect to see `/VERBOSE` or `-v` passed to the linker on the command line, as appropriate for given platform.

It doesn't matter what makefile generator is used, this behavior seems to be consistent. The two platforms of interest are.

```
qmake -spec win32-msvc2008
qmake -spec macx-llvm
```

Due to cross-platform nature of qmake, you can test it on any platform where you happen to have Qt installed. This reproduces on qmake from both Qt 4.8.4 and 5.1.1. The msvc version given in the mkspec doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `staticlib` projects, the `LFLAGS` are not passed to the linker. In fact, there's no documented way to pass such flags.

The solution is generator-dependent.

For `msvc_nmake`, `LIBFLAGS` are passed to the linker instead. To get verbose output, you might add

```
QMAKE_LIBFLAGS += /VERBOSE
```

To verify that it works, on any system, you can invoke `qmake -spec win32-msvc2008`; the particular msvc version doesn't matter.

For `unixmake`, `AR` is used to invoke the linker, so you have to add the flags to `QMAKE_AR`. To get verbose output, you might add

```
QMAKE_AR += -v
```

To verify, invoke `qmake -spec macx-llvm`; any other unix spec should work as well.